# ActiveMQ single to multiple threads...what's the best design approach?

Tags: multithreading, jms, activemq-classic

I have a question regarding workable design patterns for ActiveMQ. I have a single-threaded database client based on ActiveMQ - callers create a temporary response queue, JMS "send" a SQL query to the correct queue, and wait for a response on the temporary queue. Problem is, complex queries that run slowly mean that the single-threaded consumer bogs down...if a query takes five minutes, no other queries against that database can occur till the first one completes. The queries themselves are atomic and we don't use any manner of transaction processing at the JMS level. The solution I'm considering is to multi-thread the consumer, but I want to be sure I'm not going to run afoul of any ActiveMQ or JMS restrictions.

I understand I can just switch from queues to topics, and then I can run what I have today across many threads. It might come to this, but for now, the queue structures constitute an "API" that gets used in a lot of ways, so it's not easily changed to something topic-based.

Instead, I envision a main thread that acts just like the current consumer in terms of fetching messages from the bus, except instead of processing the messages inline (as we do now), the message would be queued to a separate thread. The child thread would do the database work, then send the results back to the original requestor on his temporary queue.

If I understand the spec correctly, I could use a single "connection" shared across threads. There would only be a single consumer, so it would just continue to be in a message receive loop, just like today. In the new child threads, we'd start a separate JMS session on the existing connection (sessions can't be shared), wait for work, process the queries, and finally send any results to the requestor's temporary queue so that he gets his output. I don't think we need massive parallelism, so I'm thinking just to have a handful of child threads preallocated and waiting for work.

Here are the questions:

1. Will I be able to send to the requestor's temporary queue from one of the child threads?
2. Can I create a single session in each of my child threads and reuse it over and over?
3. At what point would I expect a single connection to be overwhelmed?
4. Are there configuration settings on the broker that I'd have to adjust to handle the fact that I might have many times more sessions?
5. Are there any "gotchas" at the JMS level that would prevent my approach from being truly parallel, given multiple processor cores, adequate database connections and so on?
6. Is there a better approach to achieve better throughput for slow transactions?

Comment: Your question needs more focus. On Stack Overflow a question should focus only on a *single* problem. When you ask multiple questions it makes it difficult (if not impossible) to identify a correct answer. For example, what if an answer only addresses one part of your question? Assuming that it's accurate, is it "correct"? What if there are 2 answers and they each accurately address different parts of your question. Which one is "correct"? This kind of ambiguity is bad for community involvement and devalues the content. Please ask questions that focus on a single issue. Thanks!

Comment: Also, asking questions like "what is the best design approach" are also off-topic because such questions generate discussion rather than fact-based answers.

Comment: @valerie if you have additional questions, there is also the ActiveMQ slack channel

Comment: If you plan on cranking up the concurrency very far I would encourage you to take a look at [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/). It is the next-generation broker from ActiveMQ. It has very good performance and scales quite a bit better than the 5.x broker with a large number of clients. Here's [a comparison](https://softwaremill.com/mqperf-2017/#summary) involving both brokers from a few years back for a replicated persistent use-case which you may find helpful.

Comment: Thanks Justin - we've been doing some tests with Artemis and it does seem dramatically faster...our only lingering concern is whether we'll have to update the client side - we have a ton of them out there with older ActiveMQ libraries, and we can't really trigger software changes on many of them. If testing reveals that they work okay with Artemis, we may make the switch.

Comment: ActiveMQ Artemis supports the OpenWire protocol which is what the JMS client that ships with ActiveMQ 5.x speaks. Therefore all your existing clients should "just work." That's the goal anyway, and I'm not aware of any pressing bugs we have on that implementation. It's been available for a few years now so it's had a fair amount of time to bake in the community.

Comment: @Justin - yes, after some initial testing, what you suggest seems to be true...our 5.x clients using OpenWire seem to be working unchanged with an Artemis broker, just faster. Great job with that...seeing the performance differences, we're suddenly eager to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a worker model and queues are a good choice for that. Topics would be good if you wanted the *same* query request to be processed by multiple systems.

1. Yes. The only limitation on a temporary queue is that it goes away once there is no longer a message or a producer-or-consumer attached. An alternative approach is to use real queues and use ActiveMQ's garbage collection 'gc' to automatically clean them up. The advantage here, is that you have more readily available visibility to the queues in use and if there are any stragglers.
2. Sessions can be shared across producer and consumer. The JMS object hierarchy is similar to the JDBC one. You have child objects off of each other. At low load and number of connections (say, less than 8 connections per CPU core) there is no real harm in having dedicated Connection-Session-Consumer objects for each thread-- esp if you turn on pooling. It makes error handling and rollback easier.
3. Latency and/or network I/O. If you are doing less than 512 messages per second where message size is 4k or less, one connection isn't a problem.
4. Depends on total # of connections and messages-per-minute and message size.
5. Error handling. If you do JMS local transactions (recommended!) your error handling is at the session level for rollback.
6. Nope, you are good! Multi-threaded consumer is the first go-to approach for working around a slow consumer pattern.

Recommendations--

- Configure a pooled connection factory for ActiveMQ connections
- Implement the standard create connection, session, consumer, receive loop and close all resources after each message in a try {} catch {} finally {} block
- Make the code here multi-threaded --^

The connection pool prevents the broker from connection thrashing. This pattern is the most reliable for error handling and avoiding leaked resources which leads to messages loss.

Comment: Thanks Matt...I have a working single-threaded solution, and I don't want to spend a lot of energy revamping it into something multi-threaded only to find out that my design is something that ActiveMQ can't handle. Your reply gives me confidence that this won't be the case, so I'm off to give it a try.